# Tranforming to polar co-ordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

$$I = \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} xy \, dy\, dx$$

By transforming to circular polar co-ordinates, evaluate I.

How do I do this?

Is there a formula/strategy for doing this that works with different problems too?

Comment: Best strategy: *draw a diagram* of the region of integration.

Comment: I actually struggle with drawing the diagrams of these, maybe thats why I'm finding it hard, what's the best way to go about drawing the diagram?

Comment: Definitely worth practising diagrams.  In this case you could start by thinking about $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, draw the integration area, meaning the set $$\{(x,y)| x\in[0,1] \wedge y\in [0,\sqrt{1-x^2}]\}.$$

You will see that the area you draw is very simple. Once you have it, it will be easy to parametrize it using polar coordinates.